# working with bool value from View in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bool property in a model:

```
public bool IsExistSchedule {get; set;}
```

In the View I wrote the following:

```
<div id="step1" data-schedule="@Model.IsExistSchedule">
...
</div>
```

In the generated page `data-schedule` contain `True` value.
How to properly work with this value in javascript?
For example, I want to check if variable is true:

```
var isExist = $('#step1').attr('data-schedule');
if( isExist === "True")
     do something
```

I don't like this part `isExist === "True"`.  I should convert it to bool may be or something other. I'm afraid that in other browser the variable may contain other values: `true, True, "True", "true"`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally if you need any of your model for javascript, it's a good idea to do this in you views:

```
@Json.Encode(Model.IsExistSchedule)
```

This will "convert" the value into something javascript will understand, like lower-casing a boolean.

And then, like @Musa suggests, use the .data() method.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method will convert it to boolean, it is compatable with [html5 data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

```
var isExist = $('#step1').data('schedule');
if (isExist)
    do something
```

Note `"True"` does not convert to `boolean(true)` so it has to be `"true"`