# casting a bool value to bool in cshtml

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, casting

I am receiving this value from the server code in the cshtml file. Its a boolean field and I get boolean value.

```
Order="@Model.OrderModel.IsToday"
```

I tried to do this, but unfortunately it says it will be a string when I hover over ToJson.

```
Order="@Model.OrderModel.IsToday.ToJson()"
```

How to send this as bool to javascript? I need to explicit cast but my syntax of using bool is wrong I guess.

**EDIT**

When I use this `Order="@Model.OrderModel.IsToday"` in the javascript it says undefined, freaking!

Also tried this

```
Order="@Json.Encode(Model.OrderModel.IsToday)"
```

Still sends as string. I don't want to send it as string as its a boolean

Comment: Can you provide more context to your code? Is `Order` a part of JavaScript code and you are trying to assign a value from the server side?

Comment: @dotnetom: It's simple mate, nothign more you need to understand or provide a solution for what I am after. It sends the boolean value as "true" I want it to be sent as a boolean i.e true

Comment: As @dotnetom said, what exactly are you trying to do? Wild guess -> I've had issues where C# shows bool as "True" from `ToString()`, which didn't actually map to `true` in JavaScript, so I needed to call `.ToLower()` or similar.

Comment: Maybe because you're putting it in a string... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448604/using-razor-how-do-i-render-a-boolean-to-a-javascript-variable

Comment: @mmcrae: I have this sent as string from cshtml file to javascript file. This is a boolean field. I want to, hence, send as a boolean. Do you understand this layman english at least?

Comment: @mmcrae: I already followed the link you gave and then only came here. That link doesn't help me as it still send the value as string

Comment: @Learner ok so `IsToday` is a `bool` in a C# class. But what is Order? How/where are you trying to pass it to JavaScript?

Comment: @mmcrae: Mate you dont understand even my english.

Answer (score 1):

You get string value in JavaScript, because you are using quotes in your variable, so anything you have inside becomes a string.

Try this instead:

```
Order = @Model.OrderModel.IsToday.ToString().ToLower()
```

Here you convert Boolean value to string, and then convert it to lower case. You need it, because `ToString` would give you `True` or `False`, and you need the Boolean value to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: No, I already have this solution, but my lead says it shouldn't be sent as string. In the Javascript I did like ctrl.OrderToday =  Order ==='true' but he says it is not a good idea or approach. I am after sending it as a boolean. Can you make it?

Comment: See this, what you wrote is not a good practise, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733120/working-with-bool-value-from-view-in-javascript

Comment: If `IsToday` is a `bool`, then why doesn't the example in that Answer work for you? i.e. `@Json.Encode(Model.IsToday)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a string and convert to boolean in Javascript:

```
var myBool = Boolean(@Model.OrderModel.IsToday.ToString().ToLower());
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)